# ionic page displaying without header

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

i am created an app UI with ionic creator and am trying to add new page in ionic application manually but it display without header and all other pages are displaying with header.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added header bar in your index.html file

Comment: can you show your code ? create a plnkr?

Comment: <ion-view title="File Details">
    <ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
        <div class="bar bar-header">
          <h1 class="title">File Details</h1>
        </div>
        <ion-list>
     <ion-item><h3>File Referance No:</h3></ion-item><br>
     
     <ion-nav-back-button class="button-positive">
         <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
     </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>

Answer (score 2):

Hello try this code in your html page.

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome" class="padding" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content padding="false">

   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```